# When upgrading CentOS7.0 kernel version, it goes wrong when rebooting

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos

It goes wrong when I reboot my CentOS7.0 system, after executing `yum update -y kernel` and selecting the latest kernel version during rebooting.
Executing `yum update -y kernel` command, the kernel version like below:
current kernel version is `3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64`, and the latest version is `3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64`,

[image]

After executing `reboot` command, I select the first kernel (the latest version),
[image: kernel version list]
but it goes wrong, wrong details like below:

```
wn-block(0,0)  
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tained 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64  
Hadware name: ...  
Call trace:
...
Kernel Offset: disables
```

[image]

My CentOS version is 7.0, and it was installed basing on VirtualBox.Why does it go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, if you want to upgrade your CentOS system kernel, you must excute following steps:

- excuting `yum install -y kernel` or `yum update -y kernel` command;
- excuting `vi /etc/default/grub` command, set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`, it means that the first kernel will be default kernel;
- excuting `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` command(CentOS 7.0 version), it aimes to generate a new kernel configuration;
- `reboot` your system;

*Maybe I use this method just in my case, someone who have a good method can add a comment at bellow, thanks.*

Comment: `You must excute "grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg"`. This is just wrong.If it helps in your case, then you had some sort of problem during new kernel install or you manually messed up `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Could you give me a common method to solve this problem?

Comment: normal method is just `yum update kernel`. If something goes wrong (like not enough space in /boot) then act upon